# In Perl, how can extract a comma separated list of numbers from a string?

Tags: perl

I get string with split by comma and space and end with special char.
for example:

```
$str = "val=1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16&";
```

I need to get "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16.
My code in perl is

```
$str = "val=1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16&";
$str =~ /val\=(\S+)/;
print "$1\n";
```

but I get only "1,".
I need space after comma.

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern, you ask for the first sequence of non-whitespace characters following the equal sign and that's what you get. Incidentally, you do not need to escape the `=` sign in a pattern.

If you want the ampersand (`&`) to be included in the result, you can use

```
my (undef, $v) = split /=/, $str, 2;
```

If you don't, the following may suit your needs better:

```
my ($v) = ($str =~ /^val = ([^&]+)/x);
```

Comment: Can you explain the syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

if you need a string like this "1, 2, 3, ...":

```
$str =~ s/[^0-9,\s]//g;
print "$str\n";
```

if you need an array of numbers:

```
my @a = $str =~ /\d+/g;
```

Comment: Can you explain the syntax ?

Comment: You can find the explanation here: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html
Also the greatest book about regexp: http://regex.info/ -- it can change your life J.